# Failed to add edge detection - Raspberry Pi 4 GPIO

Tags: gpio, python, pi-4, spi, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I am trying to run a LoRa receiver using python

```
from time import sleep
from SX127x.LoRa import *
from SX127x.board_config import BOARD
BOARD.setup()
class LoRaRcvCont(LoRa):
    def __init__(self, verbose=False):
        super(LoRaRcvCont, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
        self.set_dio_mapping([0] * 6)    
    def start(self):
        self.reset_ptr_rx()
        self.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT)
        while True:
            sleep(.5)
            rssi_value = self.get_rssi_value()
            status = self.get_modem_status()
            sys.stdout.flush()    
    def on_rx_done(self):
        print ("\nReceived: ")
        self.clear_irq_flags(RxDone=1)
        payload = self.read_payload(nocheck=True)        
        data = bytes(payload).decode("utf-8",'ignore')
        print (data)
        self.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
        self.reset_ptr_rx()
        self.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT) 
lora = LoRaRcvCont(verbose=False)
lora.set_mode(MODE.STDBY)

#  Medium Range  Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, Bw = 125 kHz, Cr = 4/5, Sf = 128chips/symbol, CRC on 13 dBm
lora.set_pa_config(pa_select=1)
try:
    lora.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print ("")
    sys.stderr.write("KeyboardInterrupt\n")
finally:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print ("")
    lora.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
    BOARD.teardown()
```

And it is giving the error: `Failed to add edge detectio`n.

I configured the access to SPI in Raspi-Config

Installed this packages

```
pip install spidev   
pip install pyLoRa
sudo apt-get install rpi.gpio
python-rpi.gpio
python3-rpi.gpio
```

I added in GPIO Group:

```
sudo groupadd -r gpio
sudo usermod -a -G gpio pi
```

I ran it as `sudo` but it continues giving error of: Failed to add edge detection.

Anyone could help me?

Comment: What is the exact error message - should give a file and line number?

Comment: I don't see any code that would run.  WHY have you tried to install RPI.GPIO which should already be present?  It is unclear what you have actually done.

Comment: /home/pi/pySX127x/SX127x/board_config.py:61: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(BOARD.LED, GPIO.OUT)
/home/pi/pySX127x/SX127x/board_config.py:62: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(BOARD.RST, GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/pySX127x/./LORA_SERVER.py", line 98, in <module>
    lora = mylora(verbose=False)
  File "/home/pi/pySX127x/./LORA_SERVER.py", line 36, in __init__

Comment: super(mylora, self).__init__(verbose)
  File "/home/pi/pySX127x/SX127x/LoRa.py", line 95, in __init__
    BOARD.add_events(self._dio0, self._dio1, self._dio2, self._dio3, self._dio4, self._dio5)
  File "/home/pi/pySX127x/SX127x/board_config.py", line 105, in add_events
    BOARD.add_event_detect(BOARD.DIO0, callback=cb_dio0)
  File "/home/pi/pySX127x/SX127x/board_config.py", line 101, in add_event_detect
    GPIO.add_event_detect(dio_number, GPIO.RISING, callback=callback)

Comment: I understand that GPIO is used, but how i can release it for use

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error message, ‘Failed to add edge detection,’ on my Raspberry Pi 4.

After reinstalling Raspberry Pi OS, I still faced the same issue.

However, my problem was resolved by installing DietPi OS, and I also found success with Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi.